# Regular Expression in Codeigniter routes with duplicate name

Tags: php, codeigniter

What I want to do is if I got duplicate name routes,I just use one route instead using 3 routes, but I not sure what regular expression I need to use, any suggestion?

now I have this

```
product_test_1.html
product_test_2.html
product_test_3.html
```

my codeigniter routes

```
$route['product_test_1.html'] = "website/product";
$route['product_test_2.html'] = "website/product";
$route['product_test_3.html'] = "website/product";
```

something what I want (but its not working)

```
$route['/product_test/i'] = "website/product";
```

Any idea solve my problem ? 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$route['product_test_[0-9]+\.html'] = 'website/product';
```

This is about specific as you can get. The `[0-9]` means any numerical digit (could also be `\d`) and the `+` means 1 or more of the preceding token (the numerical digit).

If you want to capture just anything, the `.` token is "any character", so you can replace `[0-9]+` with `.+`, which means it will match a string of (pretty much) any character that is 1 or longer.

This creates duplicate urls for the same page, which isn't normally desirable, but maybe you specifically want that. If not, you may consider 301 redirects via `.htaccess`.

You could also pass in the ID to the function with this if that is what you are going for.

```
$route['product_test_([0-9]+)\.html'] = 'website/product/$1';
```

The parenthesis captures the number and we pass it to the URL with `$1` since it was the first capturing match captured.

Then, in you `website` controller, you could declare your `product` method as such:

```
function product($id)
```

And `$id` will automagically be the ID we passed in the URL taken from the `product_test_#.html`

Comment: thanks CWSpear comment, can i know what about if i using alphabet,such as $route['product_test_abc.html'] = "website/product";  , so my code isn't will be $route['product_test_[a-z]\.html/'] = "website/product"; ?

Comment: You could use `$route['/product_test_.+\.html/'] = 'website/product';` That will match just about anything that begins with `product_test_` and ends in `.html`.

Comment: if I hard code the routes, its working, the code will be something like this

$route['products_fidelity.html'] = "website/get_product";
$route['products_money.html'] = "website/get_product";

Comment: Oh, sorry, CodeIgniter puts the delimiters around it for you, so remove the `/` at the start and end of the url. I'll update my answer to remove them, too. I tested it though, and it should work after that change.

Comment: No problem. Sorry I missed that.